# Get names of students that have attended on particular date

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

I want to get names of all student that are attended on particular day. I am trying following query

```
select Names 
from data_table 
where ID = (select S_ID 
            from attendance_table 
            where status = 'y' and day_date = '2016-03-05');
```

But I am getting an error

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

I could do it by join the table, but I want to write in this way only.

Thank you

Comment: Replace `=` with `IN`

Comment: @MotoGP     Its working Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with a JOIN ????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this without using `JOIN's`

Using `IN` opertaor

```
SELECT Names
FROM   data_table
WHERE  ID IN (SELECT S_ID
              FROM   attendance_table
              WHERE  status = 'y'
                     AND day_date = '2016-03-05');
```

Using `EXISTS`(Preferred Method)

```
SELECT Names
FROM   data_table d
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   attendance_table a
               WHERE  d.ID = a.S_ID
                      AND status = 'y'
                      AND day_date = '2016-03-05');
```